# Possible to compile Arduino/C++ library for use in AVR assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, arduino, linker, avr

I'm working on a project writing AVR assembly for an ATmega328P (an Arduino Uno) in Atmel/Microchip Studio with AVRASM2. One of the components I'm using is the MFRC522 RFID reader/writer, for which there exists an Arduino library. I want to continue writing my code in assembly, but in the interest of time, it would be very helpful if I could include the library and call its functions from my assembly code.

I'm assuming the ideal way to do this is to compile the library into an object file so it can be linked with my assembler code. The problem is I'm unsure how to handle the linking portion. One other option I've considered is compiling the library into an object file, disassembling it with `avr-objdump` then including that disassembled code with my original assembly to be re-assembled. I have a feeling this will not work though. Maybe it might with position-independent code, but I'm fuzzy on the compiling-linking-assembling process.

Is this feasible? Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: it is not feasible. the library uses SPI library and Arduino core

Comment: "In the interest of time" and "writing AVR assembly" are two very conflicting ideas.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Not gonna lie, it was for a school project and the deadline was approaching